# Can't find my website on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

I just installed apache 2.2 on my MacBook Pro and configured the httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf files with my website but when I try to load the homepage I get the "It works!" page from apache.

The problem is that I can't understand why that page is shown. I found one instance of the "It works!" page on my filesystem and updated it but it seems that's not the one shown on the browser.

In order to map my website, I also changed my hosts file letting the domain point to 127.0.0.1.

Just to make sure the page wasn't loaded from the web, I also turned off the AirPort.

The page is shown even when I turn off apache with apachectl stop.
Any clue?

Comment: Probably the built-in Apache 2 instance, check if that's running.  Why are you installing 1.3?

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, the version I installed is the 2.2. You are right, there seems to be an httpd instance running... how can I stop it?

Comment: See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/275925/disabling-apache-on-mac-os-x) for details.

Comment: Thanks Shane, if you write it as an answer, I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the already pre-installed Apache on your OS X is not running.
You can disable it in your System preferences / Sharing / "Web Sharing".
To find out if it's running, open a terminal and run `ps auxww | grep httpd`, if it is running a process like this will show up:

`$ ps auxww |grep httpd

_www            6344   0.0  0.0  2438112    608   ??  S     7:03PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -D WEBSHARING_ON

_www            6338   0.0  0.0  2438112   1664   ??  S     7:03PM   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -D WEBSHARING_ON

root            6336   0.0  0.1  2438112   4392   ??  Ss    7:03PM   0:00.11 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -D WEBSHARING_ON`

The default Apache on Mac OS X will only display a "It works!".